# Javascript move header up on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an html header (as outlined below) that contains a main nav bar and a side bar. I'm trying to scroll this up 85px when a user scrolls down the page to hide the top nav bar using the javascript below to add the css class "nav-up". I'm not having any joy at all with this and cant figure out why they javascript is not apply this rule on scroll, does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here, I cant seem to figure this out at all!?

Basic HTML structure

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header nav-down" role="banner">
   <div id="navbar" class="navbar">
   </div><!-- #navbar -->
   <div id="sidebar">
   </div><!-- #sidebar -->
</header><!-- #masthead -->
```

CSS to apply

```
.nav-up {
    top: -85px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
    // Hide Header on on scroll down
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = 85;

$(window).scroll(function(event){
    didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
    if (didScroll) {
        hasScrolled();
        didScroll = false;
    }
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    // Make sure they scroll more than delta
    if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
        return;

    // If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
    // This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
    if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
        // Scroll Down
        $('header').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
    } else {
        // Scroll Up
        if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
            $('header').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
        }
    }

    lastScrollTop = st;
}
</script>
```